# Problems Installing Eclipse and Ruby Plugin

Tags: ruby, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin, ruby-development-tools

I installed Eclipse on my Ubuntu machine and then the Ruby Development Tools (RDT), but it would crash when I try to alter certain features, like having line numbers, how far back to have history, and the code coloring scheme didn't work fully. I decided to try to uninstall Eclipse by doing `sudo aptitude remove Eclipse` and then `sudo aptitude install eclipse` but instead it installed it back with the broken Ruby plugin. I also tried aptitude purge but that didn't help either.

How can I freshly reinstall Eclipse and get a properly working Ruby plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I still haven't figured out how to do it via aptitude, but downloading eclipse from their home page works.

Comment: Correct.  They should just remove IDE's and such, like the JDK, from apt, as it's less than useless.  For Java, Ruby et. al. you just have to use RVM (Ruby Version Manager) and such, and direct downloads.   Note that RVM isn't even packaged correctly, even though it's in apt.  You  have to do it all manually :(